# Kendo grid column template for column with values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

My kendo grid has special column with values: "Unpaid", "Paid". From backend arrives 0 - means "Unpaid", 1 - means "Paid".

My config for this column:

```
{
columnMenu: true
encoded: true
field: "Invoice__state"
filterable: {cell: {…}}
resizable: true
sortable: true
title: "State"
type: "string"
values: Array(2)
0: {value: 1, text: "Paid"}
1: {value: 0, text: "Unpaid"}
}
```

Everysing fine (pic 1).

Now I need to make some markup for column - red for Unpaid, green for Paid. I want to use template for column. I just add simple template

```
template: "<span class="label label-danger">#: Invoice__state #</span>"
```

But now I see 0 or 1 instaed Unpaid or Paid (pic 2).

How I can modify template to show label instead values ?

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRaLd.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhrwH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with help of attribute by condition.

Here code for  your reference.

CSS Block :

```
  <style>
.red{
    color:red;
}

.green {
    color:green;
}
</style>
```

Javascript Block:

```
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
columns: [
{ field: "productName" },
{ field: "category", values: [
{ text: "Beverages", value: 1 },
{ text: "Food", value: 2 }
],attributes: {
            class: "#=category ==1 ? 'red' : 'green' # #console.log(data)#"
          } }
],
dataSource: [
{ productName: "Tea", category: 1 },
{ productName: "Ham", category: 2 }
]
});
</script>
```

Comment: With this template I see green "1" and red "0" instead red "Unpaid" and green "Paid".

Comment: @Nickolay It would be great if you provide sample code in dojo to find issue.

Comment: @Nickolay it is okay with hard coded ?  'template': '#if (category == 1) {#  <span style=\'color: red;\'> Beverages </span>  #} else {#  <span style=\'color: green;\'>Food</span>  #}#'

Comment: Hardcode doestn matter. Question about column with "values" and "template" param. You can use any template with or without if statments. Column shoult show column value with some markup over template

Comment: @Nickolay So why don't you write this way 'template': '#if (category == 1) {# <span style=\'color: red;\'> Beverages </span> #} else {# <span style=\'color: green;\'>Food</span> #}#'

Comment: This template in example can be replaced by 'template': '#: category #'. In second column you will see "1" or "2", after that delete template from config you will see "Beverages" and "Food". Do you see difference with and without template ?

Comment: Actually 'values' field also used in filter. And it is very good. So I need solution which do not use litteral values in template (in template should containt only field name, 'if' statments, other statments, js statments etc, anything except literal valies which represents in values field.

Comment: @Nickolay I have edited my answer with new reference, please have look and let me know.

Comment: Your idea use attributes is brilliant.

Comment: @Nickolay Your welcome ! please marked as answer if solved your problem by this answer.